# Invalid value 'PROJECT' when adding RAW image to project

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcloud

```
$ gcloud compute images create image99 --source-uri gs://bucket99/1234z.image.tar.gz
NAME PROJECT ALIAS DEPRECATED STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.create) Some requests did not succeed:
- Invalid value 'PROJECT'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'
```

I'm using this URI scheme to add a RAW image to my project but returns the above error. I created a project and uploaded 1234z.image.tar.gz in storage -> cloud storage. How do I add the image to my project?

```
gs://BUCKET_NAME/IMAGE_NAME.image.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because gcloud configuration is populated with incorrect project name. Use the following command with correct name of your project:

$ gcloud config set project PROJECT_NAME